# Query Fields Sets in Custom Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I query my created `LPG_SAP_Opportunity_Clone_Fields` and get the list of fields inside it in my Controller Extension called `LPGVSPOpportunityCloneControllerExt` and then Query the `Opportunity` which is my standard controller via the `ID` that I've taken.

This is my controller Extension

Please Help me Thanks

```
    public class LPGVSPOpportunityCloneControllerExt {

    private ApexPages.StandardController ctrl;

    public LPGVSPOpportunityCloneControllerExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    ctrl = controller;


    }

    public void getControllerID(){

    Opportunity oppor = (Opportunity) ctrl.getRecord();
    ID opportuniyID = (ID) ctrl.getRecord().get('id');

    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schema.FieldSet and Schema.FieldSetMember methods to dynamically get all the fields in the Opportunity_Fieldset field set for the Opportunity object. The list of fields is then used to construct a SOQL query that ensures those fields are available for display.

**Apex**:

```
public class OpportunityDetails {

public Opportunity opp { get; set; }

public OpportunityDetails (ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
    String opportuniyID =(String)ctrl.getRecord().get('Id');
    String query = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
        query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
    }
    query += 'Id, Name FROM Opportunity where Id=: opportuniyID';
    opp = (Opportunity)Database.query(query);
}

public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
    return SObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.Opportunity_FieldSet.getFields();
}
```

}

**VF Page**:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityDetails">
    <apex:form >

      <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Details">
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity">
              <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Name}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>

          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Other Details">
              <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!opp[f.fieldPath]}" 
                      required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"/>
              </apex:repeat>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

To verify the functionality, you can create a URL with the VF page as-
https://your_org_instance/apex/OpportunityDetails?id=*************

See [FieldSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fieldsets_describe.htm) class

Comment: Hi Can we chat about this one?

Comment: Are you facing any issue/exception in your code?

Comment: Cause Actually I don't know If I am doing the right thing because I incorporated your code to my code and it throws no error. How can I test it if it works?

Comment: I have edited the code to include VF page and extension class. You can verify this functionality on UI and later on need to write a test class to verify the functionality for its correctness.

Comment: Hi I actually Tried it changing some minimal codes and then tried to add an Opportunity ID it throws this error duplicate field selected: Name 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified. Does this mean that It works?

Comment: "Your development organization has been notified." It means exception has occured while executing the code. Salesforce send a email which contains debug logs for that execution. Are you still receiving an error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47339/discussion-between-jmdf-and-devendra).